# Screen scraping in Java

Tags: java, screen-scraping

I'm trying to create an application, written in java, that uses my university class search function. I am using a simple http get request with the following code:

```
public static String GET_Request(String urlToRead) {

    java.net.CookieManager cm = new java.net.CookieManager();
    java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(cm);

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    BufferedReader rd;
    String line;
    String result = "";

    try {

        url = new URL(urlToRead);     
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();    
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           result += line;
    }

    rd.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

But it is not working.

Here is the url I am trying to scrape:
https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?c=TEMPE&s=CSE&n=100&t=2141&e=open&hon=F

I tried looking into jsoup but when I go to their try jsoup tab and fetch the url it is coming up with the same results as the get request is coming up with.

The, repeated, failed results that I'm getting with the http get request and jsoup is that it is bring up the search page of the university but not the actual classes and information about if they are open or not.

What I am ultimately looking for is a way to scrape the website that shows if the classes have open seats or not. Once I get the contents of the web page I could parse through it I'm just not getting any good results.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a single URL that works in your browser? That one seems to be missing request parameters.

Comment: That url *should* work in a browser... here it is again.. https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?c=TEMPE&s=CSE&n=100&t=2141&e=open&hon=F

Comment: It does, but it doesn't display the search results in my browser - it asks for more input.

Comment: Then that is my problem I don't have a correct url because the java get request is getting the same thing you are, empty search result asking for more input.

Comment: Try using firebug to capture the required header(s).

Comment: I tried a new browser that's never visited the university site (so with clear cookies) and it is redirecting the URL I'm supplying it with to another url. So I'm not exactly sure how to properly place the request parameters.

Comment: Just go to the search form and check the input tags. The names of those are your parameters

Comment: Your university really doesn't want you to do this (20+ redirects); and they probably have something in your Code of Conduct about not doing this. If they don't, and you really want it to work; try Selenium to control firefox, chrome or ie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a cookie to answer the initial course offerings question:

> **class search    course catalog**
>   Indicate which course offerings you wish to see
>   * ASU Campus
>   * ASU Online

You do this by simply adding

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "onlineCampusSelection=C");
```

to the `HttpURLConnection`.

I found the cookie by using Google Chrome's Developer Tools (Ctrl-Shift-I) and looked at `Resources` tab then expanded `Cookies` to see the `webapp4.asu.edu` cookies.

The following code (mostly yours) gets the HTML of the page you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(download("https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?c=TEMPE&s=CSE&n=100&t=2141&e=open&hon=F"));
}

static String download(String urlToRead) {
    java.net.CookieManager cm = new java.net.CookieManager();
    java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(cm);
    String result = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "onlineCampusSelection=C");

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line + "\n";
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Although, I'd use a real parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) or [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) to do the actual parsing job.